# Unexpected behavior of expr

Tags: linux, shell, expression

It may sound a bit trivial but it actually is quite frustrating:
Can anyone explain me this:

```
[~:user$]expr 3 + 2
6
[~:user$]expr 3 / 2
1
[~:user$]expr 3 * 2
expr: syntax error
```

When the man page for `expr` precisely specifies that ARG1 * ARG2 is arithmetic product of both.

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to quote the `*`, because otherwise the shell attempts file name expansion.

```
$ expr 3 '*' 2
6
```

Answer (score 5):

This should be enough:

expr 3 \* 2

Answer (score 3):

@OP, its entirely up to you, but i would still suggest to use shell internal addition operation instead of calling external expr

```
$ echo $(( 3*2 ))
6
```

If you require more advance maths operations, use bc(dc) or awk.

Answer (score 2):

`*` is expanded by your shell before it reaches `expr`, therefore it contains `Documents`, `Videos`, `Work`, `nsfw`, etc.

Comment: you mean the contents of current directory?